# Suggested distro for powerpc G4, after Lubuntu went EOL and Debian dropped support

Tags: powerpc, distro-recommendation

I have an old and trusty Mac Mini G4 that is happily doing many services in my home.
Sadly both Lubuntu 16.04 and Debian now dropped powerpc support.

Is there any hope to keep on using this machine and updating it?

Is there maybe any distro that allows me to download source code from internet and compile it locally almost automatically?

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Is_Ubuntu_supported_on_PowerPC.3F

Comment: Not in anything on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu now only supports 64-bit PPC (*ppc64el*) which is no good for you sorry.  I'd suggest SE's Unix & Linux.   FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 has been EOL awhile now, flavors only had 3 years of support with the exception of Kylin in 16.04 which was given 5 years.